# perl symbolic linked path

Tags: perl, scripting, symlink

I have a script under say `/a/b/c/a.pl`. But I'm accessing this by using `/a/symlink/c/a.pl`. When I'm running the script using the symlink path how can I read the path?

- when I use `/a/b/c/a.pl`, I should get `/a/b/c`
- when I use `/a/sl/c/a.pl`, I should get `/a/sl/c`

Comment: isnt this the name of one of death's albums?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're asking but `FindBin` will probably do what you want.  See `perldoc FindBin` and read about `$Bin` and `$RealBin`.

If `FindBin` is not what you want, try:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Cwd;
use File::Basename;

my $i_am_at = dirname( $0 );
if( $i_am_at eq '.' ){
  $i_am_at = cwd();
}
print "I am at $i_am_at\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Think `$0` is the variable you're after.

Answer (score -1):

For *nix systems at least, you can use `$ENV{PWD}` or `` `pwd` ``.

Comment: `$ENV{PWD}` will only get your working directory, which might not be at all related to where the script is located.

Comment: Ah, right. Some how I got stuck assuming that the script was being run from the directory it was in (_i.e._, `cd /a/sl/c/; perl a.pl`). Probably because I was testing with `perl -e ..`.

Comment: `use File::Basename;

my $script_path = dirname($0);

if ($script_path eq ".") {
    $script_path = $ENV{PWD};
}

#works for me`